# Openpyxl AttributeError: NoneType object has no attribute 'date1904'

Tags: android, python-2.7, xlsx, openpyxl

I am running a script on QPython2 for Android that uses openpyxl to modify an xlsx file. All works fine when I run the script for the first time with an xlsx file produced with excel but when I open the spreadsheet with WPS office, save it and run the script again I get:

```
 AttributeError: NoneType object has no attribute 'date1904'
```

Is it because WPS office is not aware of some dark magic that Microsoft used to create the xlsx file format or does the problem lies somewhere in openpyxl?

Comment: There has been some discussion about this recently on the openpyxl mailing list. That, with a sample file, is the best place to ask this question.

Comment: I use openpyxl 2.4.0, same error.